# Using \big| and \right| versus \bigr\rvert and \right\rvert

Tags: math-mode, symbols, best-practices, delimiters

Based on the answers to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/19480/71531) (about `\bigl`, `\bigr`, `\big`, etc.) and [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498/71531) (about `\lvert`, `\rvert`, `|`, etc.), I would think that anytime one used a vert bar to delimit on the right they should write `\rvert`, `\bigr\rvert`, etc., or `\right\rvert` (or `\mright\rvert`). However, I feel like I am seeing these mixed and matched in some answers. Take for example the excerpt

```
\right|_{#2} % this is the delimiter
```

from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/22255/71531), or the excerpt

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\evalat}{sO{\big}mm}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\mleft. #3 \mright|_{#4}}
   {#3#2|_{#4}}%
}
```

from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/294528/71531). Why is it appropriate to use the different combinations here?

Comment: Because most of the time it is correct, and there's no need to be “perfect”. But in your last excerpt you could simulate `\(b|B)i(g|gg)r\rvert` converting `{#3#2|_{#4}}` into `{\mathopen{}#3\mathclose{#2\rvert}_{#4}}`.

Comment: When it comes after `\left`, `\right`, `\bigl`, `\bigr`, etc., there is actually no difference between `|`, `\vert`, or `\lvert`.

Comment: @Manuel Is there any difference between `\mathclose{#2\rvert}` and `\mathclose{#2}\rvert`?

Comment: @justin In that snippet `#2` is by default `\big` and is intended to be whatever size you choose so *yes, there's a difference*. `\mathclose{\big\rvert}` has a meaning; `\mathclose{\big}\rvert` will throw an error.

Answer (score 16):

OK, the short answer is in the comments; here is the *looong* one.

**Please note:**  This answer applies to the original TeX by Knuth, to eTeX, and to pdfTeX.  I don’t know how character input in math mode and math fonts are managed in other typesetting engines, *e.g.*, in XeTeX.  Moreover, in principle the **inputenc** package could interfere in the processes described below, and this is briefly discussed at the end.

Already existing answers that give useful information about this subject
are, among others:

- [What is the differences between mathcode and catcode and how can I use mathcode?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109440)
- [Why does \big\setminus not work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282134)

---

### Character tokens, their math codes, and kinds of atom

As you know, when TeX is reading from the input file a formula to be
typeset, the input tokens are processed in “math mode”.  Most of these
input tokens will be simple characters like “x”, “y”, “+”, “=”, and so on, representing syntatic units of the formula: for example, “x” and “y” are variables, “+” is a binary operation, “=” is a relation, etcetera.  Of course, though, there are also many mathematical symbols that cannot be represented by the simple characters used in ordinary text, and are therefore input as control sequences: for example, `\sum`, `\int`, `\cup`, `\cap`, etc,, but also `\langle` or `\rangle`.  Obviously, `|` falls within the first case, while `\vert`, `\lvert`, and `\rvert` within the second.

Now, irrespective of the method used to input it, for each character that
TeX must *typeset* in a formula, it needs to know:

1. where to take the character from, that is, from which font
   and from which position within that font;
2. which kind of syntactic entity the character represents, that is,
   whether it is a variable, a binary operation, a relation, and so on.

TeX needs the information mentioned in 2 because the spacing between
adjacent characters in a formula depends on it: for example, in the formula
`ax+by=0`, no space should be inserted between the variables “a” and “x”,
or between “b” and “y”, but, on the contrary, the “+” and the “=” symbols
should be separated from the surrounding elements by some amount of space
(actually, “=” requires a thicker space than “+”).

Now, the problem arises of how to specify all this information, for each of
the possible input tokens, in a flexible and reconfigurable way, so that,
for example, the convention that “+” is a binary operator and “=” a
relation symbol is not hard-wired in the code of TeX itself.  You can
already guess that this is not at all a problem for control sequences like
`\cup`, `\vert`, or `\lvert`: after all, control sequences can stand for
arbitrary “programs”, so you can easily pack as much information as you
want inside them (we’ll see the details below).  But how is this
information specified for simple characters like “x” or “+” (or “|”)?

Answer: by associating to each character a so-called “math code”.  TeX
maintains internally a table consisting of 256 entries, each of which can
hold a 16-bit integer (although, with one exception, only 15-bit values are
actually used): for each input character, the integer contained in its
associated entry specifies the necessary information.  (This is called the
`\mathcode` table, and is very similar to other TeX tables, like the tables
of `\catcode`s, of `\sfcode`s, of `\uccode`s, etc., you might already know
about.)  More precisely, if we represent such an integer as a string of
four hexadecimal digits

*kfpp*

with *k* varying only between 0 and 7, then:

- *k* gives the **k**ind of the symbol being typeset:
  for example, 0 = ordinary symbol, 1 = large operator (like `\sum`),
  2 = binary operator, and so on
  (see *The TeXbook*, p. 154, for the complete list);
- *f* specifies the **f**ont, through an indirect mechanism that won‘t
  be discussed here (and in which LaTeX2e’s NFSS plays its part);
- *pp* indicates the **p**osition within that font.

The details of how this “`\mathcode`” table is set up and managed are
*much* more complicated in LaTeX2e than they were in the plain TeX format
described in the *The TeXbook*, and even touching them upon here is
unfeasible (see the NFSS documentation).  For the sake of answering our
question, however, it suffices to know that TeX has “some place” to look at
when it needs to know what **k**ind of symbol it is about to typeset.  Let
us recap once more:

- TeX looks at the `\mathcode` table only when it is processing
  a character token in math mode (actually, this statement should be
  refined, but let us pass over the TeXnicalities);
- if so, it looks up the corresponding entry in the table,
  whose contents specify, among other things, the kind of syntactic
  entity that the character in question represents;
- an atom of that kind is eventually appended to the current math list,
  possibly after attaching a superscript or a subscript to it.

---

### Math characters and kinds of atom

In text mode, you can specify a character to be typeset not only by
including that literal character in the input, but also by means of the
`\char` primitive, equivalent to LaTeX’s `\symbol` command.  For instance,
instead of `bubble` you might write, in your source file, `\char98 u\char98 \char98 le`, and obtain exactly the same result.  Of course, the `\char`
primitive is actually useful when you need to typeset a “strange” character
like “¿”.

In a similar way, in math mode, you can use the `\mathchar` primitive to
specify any math character (or math symbol) you want.  But there is an
important difference between `\char` and `\mathchar`: whilst after `\char`
you specify only an 8-bit number, which gives just the internal code that
represents the intended character, after `\mathchar` a 15-bit integer is
expected, which contains exactly the same information that we would find
in a `\mathcode` table entry: a **k**ind, a font **f**amily, and a
**p**osition, specified in exactly the same format.  So, for instance,

```
\matchar"1350
```

is a (primitive) command, valid only in math mode, that tells TeX to
construct an Op[erator] atom (*k* = 1) containing the character found in
font number 3 (*f* = 3), whatever this means, at position number 80 (*pp* = 50 hexadecimal).  In the usual setting, this turns out to be the ∑ symbol.

Of course, `\mathchar` commands are never used directly, but through
control sequences that have been defined to act as equivalent commands.
For example, in the customary setting `\sum` has been made equivalent to
`\mathchar"1350`, and this explains why typing `\sum` in your input file
causes an Op atom containing the right symbol to be appended to the current
math list (with possible sub/superscripts).  The point to note, here, is
that this time the **k**ind/**f**ont/**p**osition information is not looked
up in a table, as in the case of “bare” character tokens, but comes with
the command itself, be it a `\mathchar` primitive or a higher-level command
like `\sum`.

Now, always assuming that the customary conventions are in force, it turns
out that, **when used by themselves and not after `\left` or `\big` or
`\biggr` or…**:

- `\vert` is eventually equivalent to `\mathchar"026A`,
  so it generates an Ord[inary] atom (*k* = 0) containing a character
  found at a certain position in a certain font;
- `\lvert` is eventually equivalent to `\mathchar"426A`,
  so it generates an Open[ing] atom (*k* = 4) containing exactly
  the same character as above;
- `\lvert` is eventually equivalent to `\mathchar"526A`,
  so it generates a Clos[ing] atom (*k* = 5) containing again
  the same character.

Moreover, one can see that the `\mathcode` associated with the “|”
character is `"026A` too, so that a simple `|` in the input behaves,
at least when it is used by itself and not after `\right` or `\Bigm` or `\Biggl` or…, exactly as `\vert`.

But this is only a simplified version of the whole story: we shall
complete the picture in the next two sections.

---

### Delimiters

Some math symbols, like parentheses and root signs, are expected to grow
with the size of the subformula they encompass, and therefore require a
special treatment.  For these, TeX provides the concepts of “delimiter” and
of “radical”, of which only the first is of concern here.

At the primitive level (TeX’s “machine language” level, as it were), TeX
treats a symbol as a delimiter only in a few, well-defined cases: after a
`\left` or `\right` command, and in connection with certain primitive
commands that deals with fractions.  For example, `(` by itself is typeset
as a “normal” (*i.e.*, non-delimiter) character, according to the rules
detailed above, but `\left(` causes TeX to treat the parenthesis as a
“delimiter”, that is, as a character that can grow.  In order to be able to
typeset such a growing character, TeX needs more information than it does
in the case of a “normal” character, because it needs to know where the
*different* sizes of the delimiter can be found.  So, instead of looking at
the math code (`\mathcode`) for that character, TeX searches another of its
internal tables, which again contains an entry for each of the 256 possible
character codes: each entry holds the so-called “delimiter code”
(`\delcode`) of the associated character, which can be either a negative
number, for characters, like “x” or “+”, that should never act as
delimiters, or a non-negative 24-bit number, that is, a sequence of six
hexadecimal digits

*fppgqq*

that specify two variants of the glyph in question, using a two-folded
version of a convention similar to the one used in the `\mathcode` table.
More precisely, the first three digits (*fpp*) indicate the font **f**amily
and the **p**osition where the smallest size of the glyph can be found, and
the last three (*gqq*) specify in a similar way where the larger sizes can
be found (actually, *qq* indicate the position within the font of the first
larger variant; still larger variants could be available, which can be
found starting from the first one by means of information included in the
font metric file itself).  It is particularly important to note that, in
this case, the information about the syntactic nature of the symbol at
hand is *not* included in its `\delcode`, because it is *not* needed: TeX
already knows this information from the command that caused it to look for
a delimiter (`\left`, `\right`, or other ones that we are not considering).

Let us further illustrate this concept with an example: When TeX
encounters, in the input, the character token `|` *by itself*, it treats it
as a “normal” symbol: it looks up its `\mathcode`, finds out that it is,
say, `"026A`, and from the first digit of the `\mathcode` it learns that
the character at hand should be appended to the current math list as (the
contents of) an Ord[inary] atom; the other three digits of the `\mathcode`
tell TeX where to find the appropriate glyph.  On the other hand, whem TeX
encounters the input, say, `\left|`, it *already knows*, from the `\left`
command itself, that an opening delimiter is required, and it only has the
problem of finding the glyph; for this, and just for this, it looks at the
`\delcode` of the ensuing `|`, from which it retrieves the necessary
information.

This works fine if the delimiter can be specified by means of a character
token, as is the case for round parentheses (`(`, `)`), square brackets
(`[`, `]`), or vertical bars (`|`); but what about delimiters like curly
braces or double vertical bars?  These, as you know, are specified through
control sequences (`\lbrace`, `\rbrace`, `\Vert` or its synonym `\|`).
Well, all of these control sequences are actually macros that expand to
appropriate invocations of another primitive command called `\delimiter`,
which is loosely analogous to `\mathchar`.

---

### The `\delimiter` command

The primitive TeX command `\delimiter` must be followed by a 27-bit
unsigned integer, that can be represented as a string of seven hexadecimal
digits

*kfppgqq*

with *k* varying only between 0 and 7.  This command can be used in all
places where TeX is looking for a delimiter (that is, after `\left`,
`\right`, and with some other primitive commands dealing with fractions),
and in this case the rightmost six digits tell TeX where to find the glyph
for the delimiter in exactly the same way as a `\delcode` would do.  Now,

```
\left \vert
```

works precisely in this way: `\vert` is a macro that expands to
`\delimiter "026A30C`, so the above line expands to

```
\left \delimiter "026A30C
```

and TeX knows that it has to construct an opening delimiter (because of the
`\left` command) whose small variant is found in font **f**amily 2 (TeX
knows which font this is) at **p**osition 106, and whose first larger
variant is found in font 3, position 12.  The question is: what the hell is
the digit *k* provided for?

Well, we all know that we are allowed to use `\vert` not only after `\left`
or `\right` (or `\bigl`, etc.)  but also by itself, and in this case it is
completely equivalent to a lone `|`.  This is because the `\delimiter`
command is permitted to appear also in places where TeX is *not* looking
for a delimiter; in this case, the last three hexadecimal digits of the
ensuing number are dropped, and the command behaves as it had been a
`\mathchar`.  In other words, when it does *not* follow `\left`, etc.,

`\delimiter "`*kfppgqq*

acts exactly as

`\mathchar "`*kfpp*

This time, *it is from the k digit* that TeX learns which kind of atom it
has to construct, and this is the reason for providing it.  Thus, you can
define `\vert` to expand to `\delimiter "026A30C`, and this definition
will work in every situation.

---

### The answer, at last!

We are finally in a position to answer the question that has been asked.
Consider the following input samples:

- `|` by itself: TeX looks at the `\mathcode` associated with `|`,
  from which it learns *both* where to find the relevant glyph
  *and* which kind of atom to construct.
- `\left|` or `\right|`: TeX *already knows* that it has to construct
  a left (resp., a right) delimiter, and looks at the `\delcode` of `|`
  just in order to learn where to find the necessary glyph(s).
- `\vert` by itself: this is a macro which expands to
  `\delimiter "026A30C`; in this context, this acts as it had been
  `\mathchar "026A`, and the first digit of the number `"026A`
  tells TeX which kind of atom to construct (the following three,
  where to find the glyph, its small variant being always used
  in this case).  So, an Ord[inary] atom (*k* = 0) is constructed
  here.
- `\left\vert` or `\right\vert`: the first of these expands to
  `\left \delimiter "026A30C`.  TeX already knows that a left delimiter
  is being asked for, and therefore *ignores* the first digit of the
  number `"026A30C`, and uses the remaining digits to learn where to
  find the glyph(s) it needs.  The effect of `\right\vert` is analogous.
- `\lvert` by itself: this is a macro which expands to
  `\delimiter "426A30C`; in this context, this acts as it had been
  `\mathchar "426A`, and the first digit of the number `"426A`
  tells TeX which kind of atom to construct, which, this time,
  is an Open[ing] atom (*k* = 4); the following three digits tell TeX
  where to find the appropriate glyph, its small variant being always
  used in this case.
- `\left\lvert` or `\right\lvert`: the first of these expands to
  `\left \delimiter "426A30C`.  TeX already knows that a left delimiter
  is being asked for, so it ignores the first digit of the
  number `"426A30C`, and uses the remaining six just to locate the
  necessary glyph(s).  Similarly for `\right\lvert`.
- `\rvert` by itself: exercise.  (Hint: `\rvert` expands to
  `\delimiter "526A30C`; *k* = 5 means Clos[ing] atom).
- `\left\rvert` or `\right\rvert`: exercise.

From the above we see that (assuming the customary `\mathcode`s and
definitions) `\left|`, `\left\vert`, `\left\lvert`, and even `\left\rvert`
are all exactly the same thing.  And the same for `\right`.

---

### What about `\bigl` and relatives?

The control sequences `\big`, `\bigl`, `\bigm`, `\bigr`, `\Big`, etc. are
macros with one argument, each of which manifactures an atom of a
predetermined kind that contains a “pseudo-delimiter” (*i.e.*, not a
delimiter in TeXnical sense) of a predetermined size; they do so by means
of a `\left`…`\right` construction that encompasses just an empty box of
the appropriate size, which is explicitly wrapped by a `\mathord`,
`\mathrel`, `\mathopen`, or `\mathclose` command (`\mathord` isn’t
actually used, because it is “implied by default”).  More precisely, as
you certainly already know:

- the `\big`, `\Big`, … series generates Ord[inary] atoms;
- the `\bigl`, `\Bigl`, … series generates Open[ing] atoms;
- the `\bigm`, `\Bigm`, … series generates Rel[ation] atoms;
- the `\bigr`, `\Bigr`, … series generates Clos[ing] atoms.

Here, therefore, the argument is used just to locate the intended glyph.

---

### A word about inputenc

For simplicity, in the above description we did not mention the fact that
the `\mathcode` table lookup happens only for character tokens whose
category code is either 11 (letter) or 12 (other).  Remember that the
**inputenc** package makes characters in positions 128 … 255 active, and
that encoding definition files can assign a particular meaning to some of
these active character, when used in math mode.  Of course, the
substitution of such an active character with its meaning happens *before*
the processes described above take place.  To make just one example, the
file `latin1.def` contains, among many others, the declaration

```
\DeclareInputMath{177}{\pm}
```

so that character number 177 will be always equivalent, when used in math
mode, to the control sequence `\pm`.  This substitution is, of course,
completely independent of the `\mathcode` machinery.

Comment: So k=4 or k=5 only gives informations about spacing, and `\left` and `\right` are used to make the char vertically stretch (and cancels spacing informations), is that right?

Answer (score 5):

Gustavo’s answer has many interesting details in it and it’s worth a careful reading. But the bulk of the matter is quite easy.

After `\left`, `\middle` and `\right` only some tokens are legal:

- a character (or a macro ultimately expanding to one) having nonnegative `\delcode`;
- a macro whose ultimate expansion starts with `\delimiter` followed by a 27 bit number.

<sup>Note that TeX performs expansion after having scanned `\left`, `\middle` or `\right`, in order to find the required character having nonnegative `\delcode` or `\delimiter` (which in turn will trigger expansion to look for a number).</sup>

Restricting to standard TeX/LaTeX (as opposed to XeTeX/LuaTeX with `unicode-math`), the only characters that have nonnegative `\delcode` are

```
( "028300
) "029301
. 0
/ "02F30E
< "26830A
> "26930B
[ "05B302
\ "26E30F
] "05D303
| "26A30C
```

A typical macro of the second kind is defined in plain TeX by

```
\def\rangle{\delimiter"526930B }
```

In LaTeX this is written

```
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rangle}{\mathclose}{symbols}{"69}{largesymbols}{"0B}
```

which is just boilerplate code for saying essentially the same thing (in a clearer fashion).

<sup>There *is* an important difference: instead of hardwiring the math group (or family) numbers like in plain TeX, LaTeX uses symbolic names.</sup>

A `\delcode` is a 24 bit number; the difference with a `\delimiter` code is that the leftmost three bits in a `\delimiter` code specify the type of the symbol, in case it is not used in the context of `\left`, `\middle` or `\right` (henceforth LMR). So, for example, `\rangle` builds a **Close** atom as regards to spacing (first hexadecimal digit 5 in plain, `\mathclose` in LaTeX).

To the contrary, when used in LMR, these three bits are ignored, because TeX already knows the type (**Open**, **Ord** or **Close**, respectively) to assign. What the rightmost 24 bits mean is not really relevant.

How do `\bigl`, `\big` and `\bigr` enter the game, together with their siblings? They are actually `\left` in disguise, but buried in a type assigning command, respectively `\mathopen`, `\mathord` and `\mathclose`. There's also `\bigm` that builds a **Rel** atom in the same way:

```
\math<X>{\left<token><box>\right.\kern-\nulldelimiterspace}
```

is done, where `<token>` is the one following `\big` and friends, `<box>` is an appropriately sized box (for distinguishing between `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` and `\Bigg`), and `<X>` is `open`, `ord`, `close` or `rel`, depending on which one among `\bigl`, `\big`, `\bigr` and `\bigm` (or friends) is called. In particular `\big` and friends constitute LMR context.

There is no difference whatsoever between

```
\big| \big\lvert \big\rvert
```

or between

```
\bigl| \bigl\lvert \bigl\rvert
```

Similarly, `\left|`, `\left\lvert` and `\left\rvert` are exactly the same, because `|`, `\lvert` and `\rvert` all point to the same character (technically, the least significant 24 bits in the `\delcode` or `\delimiter` code are the same).

---

You may have noted that `>` and `\rangle` share the least significant 24 bits respectively in the `\delcode` and in the `\delimiter` code; the same happens for `<` and `\langle`. This allows one to say

```
\left<
\bigl<
\Bigl<
```

(or even `\big<`, but it would be wrong) instead of using `\langle`; similarly for `\rangle`.

The distinction between `|` (or the synonym `\vert`), `\lvert` and `\rvert` is significant only when they don't appear in an LMR context.

The simplest example where this can be seen is in

```
\log|-2|
\log\lvert-2\rvert
```

The correct one is the latter; the former would result in

> log`<thinmuskip>`|`<medmuskip>`-`<medmuskip>`2|

whereas the latter gives the correct

> log|-2|

---

In conclusion: use `\bigl\lvert` if you feel more comfortable, but `\bigl|` is shorter and comes to the same thing.

Comment: I don't think `\log\lvert` is necessarily better than `\log|`. `\log<thinmuskip>x` = `\log(x)`, `\log<thinmuskip>|x|` = `\log(|x|)`. I'm not saying it's worse either, just pointing that I don't see that clarity in which one is better.

Comment: @Manuel The status of `|` as a delimiter is always dubious; I'd consider it at the same level as a parenthesis, so `\log(x+y)` should be the same as `\log|x+y|`.

Comment: I’ve noticed another minor point: when you say “when used in LMR… TeX already knows the type (Open, Ord or Close, respectively) to assign”, you seem to be suggesting that `\left|`, say, creates an atom, which, TeXnically, is not correct (as you know very well).  In my answer I’ve been very careful to never speak of atoms when boundary items are actually involved: may I suggest that you be consistent with this?  Sorry for being so fussy, but the important point is involved, here, there being not an atom, an “LMR”-delimiter cannot carry sub/superscripts by itself.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti White lie… `;-)` It makes small difference to the user whether `\left(` creates an *Open* atom or rather a more complex structure. One has just to remember that `\left` and `\right` should be balanced. And yes, a `\right` delimiter *does* carry sub/superscripts.

Comment: OK, fair enough… :-)  But it is the subformula that the delimiter encompasses that actually carries the sub/superscript.  (Page 150.)

Comment: @Manuel: I’ve accustomed to _always_ enclose the argument of a logarithm within parentheses: that is, `\log(x)`, never `\log x`.  So, what I would actually write for egreg’s example is `\log\bigl(\lvert -2\rvert\bigr)`!

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I *never* add parentheses around the argument of log, sin or cos if not really necessary. Writing `\sin 2x` has no ambiguity, as multiplication by explicit numbers ties more than applying the sine.

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti I agree with egreg, at least when lots of trigonometric functions or logs are used, it's much more readable (at least to me) without parenthesis.