# How to declare a delimiter to be a left or right delimiter?

Tags: math-operators, delimiters, bigdelim

TeX knows the difference between a "left" and a "right" delimiter (e.g. `(` and `)`) and adjusts spacing accordingly.  However, the left and right versions of the delimiter `|` are the same, so TeX has to guess.  Usually TeX guesses correctly, but sometimes it does not.  Now, I know that I can use `\left` and `\right` to force TeX to consider a given `|` as a left or right delimiter, however these have the additional effect of changing the size (which maybe I don't want).  Even the smallest "big" commands `\bigl` and `\bigr` increase the size (albeit only a small amount).  Is there a way to make `|` a left or right delimiter without changing its size at all?

Here is a specific example where I know how to do it, but it isn't a general solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

$|\operatorname{A}|$

$|{\operatorname{A}}|$

$\left|\operatorname{A}\right|$

\end{document}
```

The spacing is incorrect on the first line and correct on the second and third lines.  The second line works well, but seems a bit hacked to me.  The third line isn't good since it would increase the size of the delimiters if the stuff in between were taller (and maybe I don't want that).

(Yes, I know that the reason the spacing is incorrect on the first line is because TeX is treating the second `|` as the "argument" of `\operatorname{A}`.)

Comment: Note that if you load `mathtools, define `\abs`  with `DeclarePairedDelimiter||`, you won't have this problem, and it will be shorter to type.

Comment: @Bernard Cool, thanks, I'll have to check out `mathtools`!  This doesn't solve everything though, since if I have an equation with more than two `|`, how will it know how to pair them up?

Comment: Could give more details? It's not very clear to me.

Comment: It is always possible to add `\mathopen` or `\mathclose` before a symbol to force interpretation of that symbol as an opening atom or a closing atom, respectively.  For example, `$\mathopen|-x\mathclose| \neq |-x|$`.

Comment: @Bernard for example `|a|b|c|` could be either `\left|a\left|b\right|c\right|` or `\left|a\right|b\left|c\right|`

Comment: @GuM that seems like an answer to me, why not post it as one?

Comment: Your examples would be written differently: either`\abs{a\abs{b}c}` or \abs{a}b\abs{c}. Anyway to add the (implicit) `\left ... \right`, you have to use `\abs*{...}`.

Comment: @Bernard Ah, ok, I didn't realize you were defining a macro to produce a *matching pair*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you say, in a math formula, `\mathopen|`, then the vertical bar will be interpreted as an Open atom (*i.e.*, a left delimiter), yet its size won’t be changed.  Similarly, `\mathclose|` yields a Close atom (*i.e.*, a right delimiter) without any change in size.  See also the answer to Exercise 18.14 in *The TeXbook*.  MWE:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.



\begin{document}

For example, \( \mathopen|-x\mathclose| \neq |-x| \).

\end{document}
```

Notwithstanding this, I think that the solution that @Bernard recommends in [a comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/504755/how-to-declare-a-delimiter-to-be-a-left-or-right-delimiter#comment1275111_504755), that is, to use `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, is The Right Thing To Do.

**Edit:**
As Barbara Beeton reminds in her comment, if the problem is confined to single and double vertical bars (and if you prefer not to load the `mathtools` package, but stick to `amsmath`), you can also use the four predefined commands `\lvert`, `\rvert`, `\lVert`, and `\rVert`: `l` stands for “left”, `r` for “right”, lowercase `v` for single bar, uppercase `V` for double bar.

For a deeper discussion, see, for example, [Using \big| and \right| versus \bigr\rvert and \right\rvert](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/294753/69818) (I remember this question because one of the answers was mine!).

Comment: In `amsmath`, `\lvert` is defined to be `\mathopen` and `\rvert` is defined to be `\mathclose`.  Those definitions ensure that the spacing is appropriate for their use as "fences".  (Similarly, the double verts are defined as `\lVert` and `\rVert`.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton:  Yes, I know, but the question seemed to ask for a general method.  I’ve augmented my answer, anyway: thank you for the remark.