# Why does using \biggl <stuff> \biggl not throw an error?

Tags: math-mode, delimiters

I consider myself a recovering user of `\left...\right` and stumbled onto this issue today. I have a `\virtualparens` command that puts light gray parentheses around its argument. I can provide optional delimiter sizes (`\big`, `\bigg`, etc.). I noticed that when I provide `\biggl` no error occurs and I don't understand why. I would think `\biggl` requires a paired `\biggr` but I think this answer (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/295041/218142) explains why. I don't fully understand the argument there, but it appears that `\biggl` merely indicates sizing information and doesn't "know" what the delimiter is. Is that correct?

Also, if there is a better way to to handle the optional sizing arguments I am open to using it.

Here is my MWE:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\virtualparens}{ O{} m }{%
  \textcolor{lightgray}{#1(}#2\textcolor{lightgray}{#1)}
}%

\begin{document}
\[
  \virtualparens[\biggl]{-G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Light gray parentheses around the argument]

Comment: `\biggl` and `\biggr` are not defined as a linked pair, so they can be used to match sizes of fences where `\left` and `\right` would result in an error, such as in different cells of a table, or on opposite sides of an aligned relation.  Therefore the user has to be careful to specify the correct directionality for each such command on input.

Comment: Is what I'm doing ill-advised? If there's a better way I'm open to learning it.

Comment: Yes, it is not correct, therefore, ill advised.

Comment: The minus sign in front of the G is being set as binary subtraction, not as a unary minus.  The same happens in the first two of the four examples in @egreg's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to use `l` version on the left and `r` version on the right.  I modified your syntax a bit to achieve it.  Using two left versions does not throw an error, but it could mess up the natural spacings between surrounding material.

However, there is a drawback to using this paired approach...you can't naturally break up the argument across a linebreak, which one can do if he individually specifies the `\biggl(` and `\biggr)`.  So, you have to weigh the advantages and disadvantages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\virtualparens}{ O{} m }{%
  \textcolor{lightgray}{\csname#1l\endcsname(}#2
  \textcolor{lightgray}{\csname#1r\endcsname)}
}%

\begin{document}
\[
  \virtualparens[bigg]{-G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

I'd prefer a syntax *à la* `mathtools`, where you just specify the size with `\big` `\Big` `\bigg` or `\Bigg`. In any case you should specify the type of the objects you build, because `\textcolor` hides it.

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\virtualparens}{ O{} m }{%
  \mathopen{\textcolor{lightgray}{#1(}}% opening fence
  #2% contents
  \mathclose{\textcolor{lightgray}{#1)}}% closing fence
}
```

Here's the full example, with comparisons.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\NewDocumentCommand{\virtualparens}{ O{} m }{%
  \mathopen{\textcolor{lightgray}{#1(}}#2\mathclose{\textcolor{lightgray}{#1)}}%
}

%%% for comparison
\NewDocumentCommand{\wrongvirtualparens}{ O{} m }{% your definition
  \textcolor{lightgray}{#1(}#2\textcolor{lightgray}{#1)}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\alsowrongvirtualparens}{ O{} m }{% Steven's definition
  \textcolor{lightgray}{\csname#1l\endcsname(}#2%
  \textcolor{lightgray}{\csname#1r\endcsname)}%
}
%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \sin\wrongvirtualparens[\bigg]{-G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r}} \\
  \sin\alsowrongvirtualparens[bigg]{-G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r}} \\
  \sin\virtualparens[\bigg]{-G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r}} \\
  \sin\biggl(-G\frac{m_1 m_2}{r}\biggr)
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Do you see the difference?

Comment: I must admit the only differences I see are the spacing between `sin` and the left parenthesis and the overall width of the distance between the parentheses. Is that what I'm supposed to see? Do `\mathopen` and `\mathclose` do the same thing as appending `l` and `r` to the sizes?

Comment: @LaTeXereXeTaL That's the difference to be noted. The definition of `\Biggl(` is essentially `\mathopen{\Bigg(}` and similarly for `\Biggr`.

Comment: Maybe it’s obvious, but I don’t see it. Why does Steven’s definition give wrong spacing albeit using `\biggl` and `\biggr`?

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria Because `\Biggl` and `\Biggr` are hidden inside `\textcolor`.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can keep the decision about parentheses size to `\left...\right` primitives:

```
\def\virtualparens#1#2#3{\mathopen{}\color{lightgray}\left#1
   \color{black}#2\color{lightgray}\right#3\color{black}\mathclose{}}

$$
  \sin \virtualparens ({-G {m_1 m_2\over r}}) x
$$
compare with:
$$
  \sin \Bigl( -G {m_1 m_2\over r} \Bigr) x
$$
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand more about `\mathopen` and `\mathclose`.